# Output order in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to run the following code in a jupyter notebook within the Google colab, but the results of the print functions appears earlier than the graph visualisation, although the visualisation comes earlier in the code. Can someone explain to me why does this happen and Jupyter does not display the results as they come in the code?

```
num_nodes = 4
G = nx.DiGraph(nx.path_graph(num_nodes))
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True)

pr = nx.pagerank(G, alpha=0.8)
print(pr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Jupyter does not display the results as they come in the code.
Better use the text inside the graph or run in another code block